Is weighted $L^p$ space isomorphically $L^p$ spaces?
Let $w:\mathbb{R}^n\to ]0,\infty[$ continuous (a weight)
Is the weighted $L^p$ spaces $L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ isomorphically to $L^p$ space?
My attempt: Let $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\colon T(u)=u/w$. This application  is an isomorphism. Is it correct?

No. Take $T(u)=u/(w^{1/p})$.

Is your $T$  an isomorphism?

Yes, it surely is.
